# JSON Parse # Hastag in response

Tags: knockout.js, json, hashtag

I am using a wysiwyg editor and knockout so when I initialize my view model I parse some bootstrapped data on the page to fill in the wysiwyg and some other fields.

However when the data contains # and probably other characters knockout's parser fails with unexpected character

```
"{"text": "<font color=\"#ffcc66\">Some super sweet body content hello world&nbsp;</font>"}"

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token #
```

What is the best way to store html like this so that I can pass it back and forth between my server and view model. Was thinking might have to encode this particular field when storing and decode it on display not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was most likely the "" quote escaping that was messing everything up. I dont know if this is the best way but I encoded the text string with `encodeURIComponent` and when I put the text back in the editor I used `decodeURIComponent`.